# Enable wifi from application

Tags: android, wifi, su

I am trying to enable wifi from application.
I have tried the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "svc wifi enable"});
```

And I see that wifi is enabled but I can't find any wifi stations.
The strange thing is that I do find wifi station if I just will do the same from shell just before starting application:

```
 $ svc enable wifi
```

I don't understand what's the difference between these two scenarios, and how to make it work from application.

I also tried to call script from application which only calls the same command, But I got the same results.

Comment: Why only spit _half_ of the command. `{"su", "-c", "svc", "enable", "wifi"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/system/bin/su","-c","svc wifi enable"});
```